# Does crafting on torment 6 make better rolls on items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some friends told me to try crafting items on T6 difficult to higher the roll values. Is it really working?

Answer (score 3):

No.  What difficulty you craft items on has absolutely no effect on the rolls whatsoever.  You can craft the same gear on Normal as you can on Torment 6.  The only thing that affects the rolls is the item level itself and rarity.

As this [blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12373027360?page=4#63) says:

> Only the gear from monsters, including Rift Guardians, is affected by Difficulty level.

It's not specific to crafting, but any item generation, whether you make it or kill a monster for it.

Comment: I was under the impression that the monster level affect only drop rate. It also affects the rolls on the items?

Comment: Drop rate?  I don't believe monster level has *ever* affected drop rate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the difficulty that you're on (Normal vs. Torment)

Comment: Difficulty doesn't even affect regular equipment drop rate; only crafting materials (and legendaries, of course).  It affecting item rolls is new to me.

Comment: also your class has effect on items you craft since the loot 2.0 system.
this is especially useful if you want to gear your templar and play a wizard. In this case just log on your strength char and craft on him (: